# A question I asked may be a bit misleading, should I delete it and repost when update it?

Tags: discussion

Today I posted a question, but judging by the comments, I believe it may be a little bit far-fetched or misleading. I didn't expect it to be very difficult, but planning to update it tomorrow or the day after. There is already one answer going in the right direction, so not sure whether to delete the question and repost it later or something else?
[What number is hidden in this gallery?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33534/what-number-is-hidden-in-this-gallery)

Best, Artur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What I think you should do :

- Keep your question, **do not delete it**
- **Update your question** to correct it (as you have done)
- **Add a note** at the end of your question to explain that the puzzle have been updated and what are the reasons
- Comment on the previous answers to **warn** them that the puzzle has changed

#### The reasons you should not delete your post :

- Some users have worked on it and they can be frustrated if their work desappear
- Puzzles are edited all the time, it is very normal. It is even advised to edit your puzzle if it is too broad.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too.

Comment: Also, diamond mods **can delete** your reposts. Not everyone wants to see your thousands of deleted reposts, and some people *can* see them, so it's frustrating and vandalizing the whole site.